# How to connect to a Web Service (SOAP + DES) from iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, soap, encryption

I am really new to Xcode and I need to connect to a web service API (SOAP + DES), which means I have to send a Username, Password, Key and IV to the server before I can get the XML file and parse it.

Is there any tutorial about connecting to a Web Service API (SOAP + DES) from an iPhone?

```
    -(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender
{
    recordResults = NO;

    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
     "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
     "<soap:Header>"
     "<CredentialSoapHeader xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
     "<userID>xxxxx</userID>"
     "<Password>xxxx</Password>"
     "</CredentialSoapHeader>"
     "</soap:Header>"
     "<soap:Body>"
     "<GetNearUserByArticleLatLon xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
     "<strXML>"
                             "<XMLDATA>\n"
                             "<KeyWord></KeyWord>\n"
                             "<Lat>0</Lat>\n"
                             "<Lon>0</Lon>\n"
                             "<IP>219.71.65.55</IP>\n"
                             "<CurrentPage>1</CurrentPage>\n"
                             "<PageSize>10</PageSize>\n"
                             "</XMLDATA>\n"
                             "</strXML>"
     "</GetNearUserByArticleLatLon>"
     "</soap:Body>"
     "</soap:Envelope>"];


    NSLog(@"%@", soapMessage);

    //http://www.xignite.com/services/GetRealQuote
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api3.mmnears.com/API/api.asmx?op=GetNearUserByArticleLatLon"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/GetNearUserByArticleLatLon" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"theConnection = %@",theConnection);

    if(theConnection)
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        NSLog(@"WebData = %@",webData);

    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is null");
    }

}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response
{
    [webData setLength:0];
     NSHTTPURLResponse * httpResponse;

    httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

    NSLog(@"HTTP error %zd", (ssize_t) httpResponse.statusCode);

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
    NSLog(@"webdata: %@", data);

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"error with the connection");
    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received bytes %d", [webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"xml %@",theXML);
    [theXML release];
```

Comment: yeah^^   
change these two things '<' and '>' to wording '&lt' and '&gt'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a quick reference of it all here you have a couple of tutorials that helped me out:

1) http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app

2) http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/mugunthkumar/mknetworkkit) to get data from server.

Comment: Misses the "SOAP" part, methinks.

Answer (score 0):

see this SOAP connection tutorial:
[SOAPExample](https://github.com/ilteris/SOAPExample)

and  [SOAP Reference](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/)

Comment: hi Hector~ I got HTTP error 400 ><

Comment: do you use proxies server? if your data put in another server than add its proxies in bypass.

Comment: still not working ><  I didn't use proxy.

Comment: 2012-03-03 10:17:37.966 SOAPExample[1029:f803] Request: <NSMutableURLRequest http://api3.mmnears.com/API/api.asmx>
2012-03-03 10:17:37.971 SOAPExample[1029:f803] theConnection = <NSURLConnection: 0x6846b10>
2012-03-03 10:17:37.971 SOAPExample[1029:f803] WebData = <>
2012-03-03 10:17:38.229 SOAPExample[1029:f803] HTTP error 400
2012-03-03 10:17:38.230 SOAPExample[1029:f803] DONE. Received bytes 0
2012-03-03 10:17:38.230 SOAPExample[1029:f803] xml

Comment: check this http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html

Comment: I just found out, the API is running in the VMware. Is it gonna be a problem?

Comment: ping your host server just check for you get connection or not

Comment: omg...you are right man~ I can not ping the server~ that's why!!
thank you very much Piyush

Comment: I used the wireshark to catch the packet that i sent to the server. I found out these "forHTTPHeaderField" did not bind with XML. I am not sure why? I guess this is why the server give me the error~

Comment: I can send to the server, the connection is fine~ please help~ is there anything else I have to add in the code?

Comment: I got SoapHeader: <NSMutableURLRequest http://api3.mmnears.com/API/api.asmx>
did not have Soap Action, Host, content-type, content-length.

Comment: add your host server ip in bypass. follow this step :Network-->advanced-->proxies-->Bypass proxy settings for these Host & Domains:add your host ip in box

Comment: when i sent a request these should be sent to the server too?          POST /InStock HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 299
SOAPAction: "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"

Comment: *.local、169.254/16、192.168.0.104  but i still get the same problem~

Comment: i think i have not correctly escaped the "/" in my code,    @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
     "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" "xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
"<soap:Header>""<CredentialSoapHeader xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
 "<userID>xxxxx</userID>"
"<Password>xxxx</Password>"
"</CredentialSoapHeader>"
"</soap:Header>"
"<soap:Body>"
"<GetNearUserByArticleLatLon xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
"<strXML>"
 "<XMLDATA>\n"
 "<KeyWord></KeyWord>\n"

Comment: i cannot go into the chat room only got 11 reputation ><...

Comment: I have skype bro~ if it is ok for you

Comment: i see~ The api is at local~ so i can only do the test while i am at the office~

Comment: Hi` I have found out the problem~

Comment: change these two things  '<' and '>'  to wording '&lt' and '&gt'